# IMPORTXML with bad xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm looking for data on the Yahoo Finance website for EV / EBITDA, but xPath returns values where I can't get the ID:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CARD3.SA/key-statistics?p=CARD3.SA

xPath:

```
// * [@ id = "Col1-0-KeyStatistics-Proxy"] / section / div [3] / div [1] / div [2] / div / div [1] / div [1] / table / tbody / tr [9] / td [4]
```

There are no differences between xpath "current" and 03/31/2020 except in full xpath (one is 4 and the other 3):

current:

```
/ html / body / div [1] / div / div / div [1] / div / div [3] / div [1] / div / div [1] / section / div [3] / div [1 ] / div [2] / div / div [1] / div [1] / table / tbody / tr [9] / td [4]
```

03/31/2020:

```
/ html / body / div [1] / div / div / div [1] / div / div [3] / div [1] / div / div [1] / section / div [3] / div [1] / div [2] / div / div [1] / div [1] / table / tbody / tr [9] / td [3]
```

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`IMPORTXML` nor `IMPORTHTML` can't import the data. You should use [IMPORTFROMWEB](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) addon to do this (note : number of requests are limited with the "Free" plan) :

You'll need the following XPath :

For headers :

```
//span[.="Current"]/ancestor::tr[1]//span[text()][count(./*)=0]
```

For data :

```
//span[.="Enterprise Value/EBITDA"]/../following-sibling::td
```

Output :

[image: OutputTF]

Formula used in C4 :

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTFROMWEB(C1;C2:D2))
```

Possible alternative : GoogleAppScript to request and load the JSON data directly from the Yahoo API.

Comment: Awesome!! I never will think about this!! Thank you!! Its work!!

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I try many times, sorry